# Iterate through #defines

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a config file in my application like below. This config need to be done before build the program.

```
#define NO_OF_COLORS 8   

#define COLOR_RESPONCE_1 'R'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_2 'G'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_3 'B'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_4 'M'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_5 'C'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_6 'Y'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_7 'O'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_8 'P'
```

Inside a class I need to add these set of values to a std::vector. Is there a way to iterate through these defines. May be using a macro?

Comment: i don't think you can iterate through define as it is permanent and cannot be tampered with

Comment: Please could somebody tell me why certain programmers like macros

Comment: Also you can convert between RGB and CMYK

Comment: @ Ed Heal, `char`s are expected user inputs for a console applications. filled  vector uses to validate the inputs

Comment: English would be nice

Comment: Have you seen [this aproach](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63249/50647)? I think it will help you to change the config without the need to build the application again. Creating a class of config, will also let you get any value you want. More, you can also return a vector and iterate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library.  It provides macros that simulate control constructs and data structures for the prepropcessor. E.g. you can iterate over your colors like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define NO_OF_COLORS 8

#define COLOR_RESPONCE_1 'R'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_2 'G'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_3 'B'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_4 'M'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_5 'C'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_6 'Y'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_7 'O'
#define COLOR_RESPONCE_8 'P'

#define PRINT_COLOR(z, x, _)                    \
  std::cout << BOOST_PP_CAT(COLOR_RESPONCE_, x) << std::endl;

int main()
{
  BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO(1, NO_OF_COLORS, PRINT_COLOR, 0);
}
```

BOOST_PP_REPEAT_FROM_TO simulates loop with counter, PRINT_COLOR macro implements the loop body.

Personally I would use Boost.Preprocessor only if I have no other choice.  It only simulates control constructs and have a number of limitations (e.g. on a number of loop iterations), also debugging preprocessor code is no simpler than heavy template code.

**A note on style.** Although preprocessor is inherited from C and is necessary for separate (and also conditional) compilation, it is alien to modern C++, in fact is alien even for pre-98 C++.  If you need constants you can and should define them with **const**, **enum** (or even better with **enum class**) or **constexpr**.  These constants can be put in namespaces to avoid name clashes, they can be guaranteed to be initialized only once (**extern const**).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can iterator through macros. Pre-processor compilation may be multi-phase, but the names itself would be resolved in first pass (of preprocessing) only.

Better if you do this way:

```
const char Colors[] = {'R','G','B','C','M','Y','O','P'};
```

And then use `sizeof(Colors) / sizeof(Colors[0])` to find number of elements in this array. Iterate using a loop:

```
for(size_t index = 0; index < sizeof(Colors) / sizeof(Colors[0]); ++index)
{}
```

Or, if you are using C++11 compiler, which support range-based for loops, you may use:

```
for(char color : Colors) 
{ 
   // Use 'color'
}
```

More simply:

```
for(auto color : Colors) 
{ 
   // Use 'color'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store these in a `std::string` rather than a `std::vector`?

```
const std::string COLDATA = "RGBMCYOP";
```

You still get to access it like a `std::vector` using indexing `[]`:

```
COLDATA[3]; // == 'M'
```

Or if you still want to put that in a vector you can do so like this:

```
const std::vector<char> COLDATAVEC(COLDATA.begin(), COLDATA.end());
```

If you are using **C++11** you can put it into a `std::vector` without using a `std::string`:

```
const std::vector<char> COLDATAVEC = {'R', 'G', 'B', 'M', 'C', 'Y', 'O', 'P'};
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your own iterating machinery (limited to 10 iterations):

```
#define ITER_0(MACRO, ACTION, DATA)
#define ITER_1(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_0(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##1, DATA)
#define ITER_2(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_1(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##2, DATA)
#define ITER_3(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_2(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##3, DATA)
#define ITER_4(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_3(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##4, DATA)
#define ITER_5(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_4(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##5, DATA)
#define ITER_6(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_5(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##6, DATA)
#define ITER_7(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_6(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##7, DATA)
#define ITER_8(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_7(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##8, DATA)
#define ITER_9(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_8(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##9, DATA)
#define ITER_10(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_9(MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ACTION(MACRO##10, DATA)

#define ITER_I(ITERS, MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_##ITERS(MACRO, ACTION, DATA)
#define ITER(ITERS, MACRO, ACTION, DATA) ITER_I(ITERS, MACRO, ACTION, DATA)
```

Define actions that will get invoked on each iteration:

```
#define PRINT(MACRO, DATA) std::cout << MACRO; 
#define ADD_TO_VECTOR(MACRO, DATA) DATA.push_back(MACRO);
```

Use those actions like below:

```
std::vector<char> v;
ITER(NO_OF_COLORS, COLOR_RESPONCE_, ADD_TO_VECTOR, v)

ITER(NO_OF_COLORS, COLOR_RESPONCE_, PRINT, ~)
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31bc43f567818948)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to iterate over an enumeration. C++ does not support this (other languages, such as Java do have this behavior by default. To work around this, you want to create a data structure that is iterable, constant in length, and well defined, so it is easy to maintain.

For, example you can store the data in an `std::array` (or before c++11 `std::tr1::array`)

```
const std::array<BYTE,8> Colors = { { 'R','G','B','C','M','Y','O','P' } };
```

The `std::array` has iterators, and a `size()` operator. So you can do

```
for( std::array<BYTE,8>::const_iterator itr = Colors.begin();
     itr != Colors.end();
     ++itr )
{
    // use (*itr)
}
```

or if you want the index

```
for( std::size_t index = 0 ; index < Colors.size() ; ++index )
{
    // use Colors[i]
}
```

and in `c++11` you can use:

```
for( auto color : Colors )
{
     // use color     
}
```

You can also copy them to an `std::vector` by:

```
std::vector<BYTE> Colors_vector( Colors.begin(), Colors.end() );
```