# How do I create an expression using macros in C?

Tags: c, dynamic, macros

I need a macro that takes input as

`MACRO(x, y, z, ...)`

and expands to

`arr[0] == x && arr[1] == y && arr[2] == z ...`

Any ideas?

**arr is char[], and macro args are single chars**

Comment: I forgot to add dots .... Thank you for noticing that! Now it's ready. I want to generate some C code with macros like in above

Comment: I doubt there's a way to do this as you've outlined.  I assume you've got a bunch of these comparisons you want to do, which is why you're trying to write this macro.  What is the type of `arr[]`, and what kinds of things are you trying to compare?

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's a typo. I've fixed it

Comment: For string comparison. And also I want to learn how to use macros with auto generated indexes

Comment: The array in `char []`

Comment: `x`, `y` ,`z` ... - `char`

Comment: Macros with a variable number of arguments are tricky, and somewhat limited, and I don't think they'll be able to do this.  (I especially don't know how you'd auto-generate the indices.)  I know it's not what you asked, but I would just use `strncmp` for this: `if(strncmp(arr, "xyz" == 0) { ... }`

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need a macro that takes input character by character and what does that solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using boost preprocessor:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define MACRO_AND(Z, N_, ARGS_)  \
    BOOST_PP_EXPR_IF(N_, &&) \
    arr[N_] == BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(N_, ARGS_)

#define MACRO(...) \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT( \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), \
        MACRO_AND, \
        (__VA_ARGS__))
```

This uses `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` to iterate the variadic arguments, feeding them in as a tuple via the data parameter.  `BOOST_PP_EXPR_IF` prefixes the `&&` for all but the 0th argument.

Boost preprocessor is a header only library and can be used with C.

Demo (on coliru) [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33d129cd633c8f24).

FYI, be very careful... I'm not sure how you're going to use this for generic string inputs (e.g. if the NUL terminator comes up during the comparison).

Comment: Thanks. I don't really think that thing is possible in pure C. But anyways, I'll use your preprocessor

Answer (score -1):

#### How about this:

```c
#define MAKE_MACRO(arrname,x,y,z) (arrname)[0] == x && (arrname)[1] == y && (arrname)[2] == z
#define MACRO(arrname,x,y,z) MAKE_MACRO(arrname,x,y,z)
```

```c
int main()
{
    char arr[3] = {'a','b','c'};
    
    if (MACRO(arr,'a','b','c'))
        printf("TRUE");
    else
        printf("FALSE");
        
    return 0;
}
```

#### Useful Referecnes:

- [Iterate through #defines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501032/iterate-through-defines)
- [Converting bool to text in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29536/11465149)
- [C preprocessor: expand macro in a #warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12638158/11465149)
- [Is it possible to define same macro more than once?](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1912463/is-it-possible-to-define-same-macro-more-than-once)
- [C pre-processor defining for generated function names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1254012/11465149)
- https://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Macro-functions.html

Comment: 1. It is C not C++.

Comment: 2. what about `char arr[] = {0, 'a','b','c'}; if (MACRO(arr + 1,'a','b','c')) ...` Will it work?

Comment: `1.` Oops! thanks for the catch! @0___________

Comment: **`2.` fixed it (:**

Comment: I have different number of arguments, and your macro works only for 3 chars...